How do I download a binary file written to DotNetFiddle's sandbox?
I created a binary file while running C# code in DotNetFiddle. How do I download this file from the sandbox to my computer.  Thank you.
I have tried searching for a solution, but I haven't found one yet. Does anyone have a solution?

You can Base64 Encode the bytes and print that with Console.WriteLine(). Copy and Paste the result to a text file on your local computer. Then process it locally using Base64 Decode and there are your bytes again, ready to be saved.

As one of DotNetFiddle devs, i can provide an answer. The storage there is ephemeral and deleted after fiddle is executed. It's also not exposed publicly and not available outside of code execution.
The only ways would be to download it as part of code execution flow. a couple of ways might be:

to print Base64 like @Peter B suggested.
you can do a code that will do a HTTP POST of your binray file to some external site like requestbin.com
you can try to send an email with binary file, but then you would need to specify some smpt gateway\credentials that might be not that good.


Thank you. I used your suggestion #1, and it worked very well.
